# Is it possible to configure server for pgadmin in docker-compose instead of configuring it from pgadmin ui

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin-4

I am running pgadmin and postgres through docker-compose and both are in same network, so I am able to connect to posgtres from pgadmin after configuring the server in pgadmin. If I do `docker-compose down`, all containers are destroyed so my server configuration in pgadmin will be lost. If I do `docker-compose up` again, I will have to configure the server from pgadmin ui again. I want to avoid this manual process of configuring server in pgadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a volume and mount the volume in the pgadmin container where config is stored (/etc/pgadmin for Linux). Now your changes will be persisted across restarts.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes

Comment: Thanks, your answer solves the problem asked in my question so I am  accepting your answer.
But is it possible to configure the server from docker-compose or any other script, so that other developers in team will not have to configure it manually even for the first time. We have a wsl script where we automate all the steps for setting up our development evn. Only configuring this server is the manual step we are doing. It's not too lengthy step to do manually but it will be nice to automate 100%. :-)

Comment: Yes @AjeetSingh it can be very easily automated. If the configuration is the pgAdmin configuration. In that case, you can just keep a copy of the file with the modifications you want and then copy it to the correct directory after installation during the build only.